# Regex - Match numbers & special cases

Tags: java, regex, math

I'm trying to make a regex that would produce the following results :

- for `7.0 + 5 - :asc + (8.256 - :b)^2 + :d/3` : **7.0**, **5**, **:asc**, **8.256**, **:b**, **2**, **:d**, **3**
- for `-+*-/^^ )ç@` : nothing

It's should first match numbers which can be float, so in my regex I have : `[0-9]+(\\.[0-9])?` but it should also mach special cases like **:a** or **:Abc**.

To be more precise, it should (if possible) match anything but mathematical operators **/*+^-** and parentheses.

So here is my final regex : `([0-9]+(\\.[0-9])?)|(:[a-zA-Z]+)` but it's not working because `matcher.groupCount()` returns **3** for both of the examples I gave.

Comment: Are you trying to make a mathematical expression parser? If yes, *do not use regexes for this*

Comment: You have 3 groups in your pattern, so `matcher.groupCount()` will always return 3 (No matter what the input is). Read the [docs of the methods you are using](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#groupCount()).

Comment: @caiosm1005 Yes that's right. Can you explain why please ?

Comment: @miNde [Please see this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) - it's essentially for the same reason. Mathematical expressions aren't regular. Parsing a string requires a few steps, including tokenization and token analysis. If you'd like to go deep into it, see *[the overview of a parsing process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parser#Overview_of_process)*.

Comment: @miNde I also tried to make what you're doing with regexes once, so, talking by experience, relying solely on regexes and a few exception rules becomes a mess so big you won't be able to fully solve in the end.

Comment: @caiosm1005 Ok I will look at these links, thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Groups are what you specifically group in the regex. Anything surrounded in parentheses is a group. `(Hello) World` has 1 group, `Hello`. What you need to be doing is finding all the matches.

In your code `([0-9]+(\\.[0-9])?)|(:[a-zA-Z]+)`, 3 sets of parentheses can be seen. This is why you will always be given 3 groups in every match.

Your code works fine as it is, here is an example:

```
String text = "7.0 + 5 - :asc + (8.256 - :b)^2 + :d/3";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)?)|(:[a-zA-Z]+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);

List<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();
while (m.find()) matches.add(m.group());

for (String match : matches) System.out.println(match);
```

The ArrayList `matches` will contain all of the matches that your regex finds.
The only change I made was add a `+` after the second `[0-9]`.
Here is the output:

```
7.0
5
:asc
8.256
:b
2
:d
3
```

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html) is some more information about `groups` in java.

Does that help?

Comment: I am not the downvoter. But why did you change his regex? It works just fine.

Comment: Omg that was just that... thank you. So I have no choice but to loop with find() to get the number of groups in the expression that matched the regex ? I wonder why there isn't something like a size() method.

Comment: No problem! ^_^ Yeah, in Python you can create a list simply by `re.findall()`. I'm not sure why you have to loop it in Java, but it's not that big of a deal i guess.

Answer (score 0):

```
([^\()+\-*\s])+ //put any mathematical operator inside square bracket
```

Comment: Have you tried it? Running this regex against OP's input does not produce his desired output.

Comment: it still matches `^`. That's not in his desired output.

Comment: @jlordo op stated match `anything` except mathematical operator..but hey i add `\s` to exclude whitespace

Comment: He didn't express that clear enough, but his example shows. Your regex still matches `^` wich the OP interprets as the mathematical power operator.

Comment: funny, it should not match ^. ^ means "not" inside []. And no, I did not test it.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is correct, run the following code:

```
    String input = "7.0 + 5 - :asc + (8.256 - :b)^2 + :d/3"; // your input
    String regex = "(\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)|(:[a-z-A-Z]+)"; // exactly yours.
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
```

Your problem is the understanding of the method `matcher.groupCount()`. [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#groupCount%28%29) clearly says

> Returns the number of capturing groups in this matcher's pattern.